React state variable throws error when updated using ++ prefix
I'm Fairly new to React and JS, just exploring the nitty-gritties of the lang.
I'm trying to compare the difference in updating the state variable "counter", using the ++ operator( and by idiomatic way of counter + 1).
The error I get for the following snippet is:
function App() {
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);

  const incrementCounter = () => {
    setCounter(++counter);
  };

  console.log(counter);

return (
    <>
  <button onClick={incrementCounter}>Increase </button>
    </>

App.jsx?t=1714542208954:31 Uncaught TypeError: Assignment to constant variable.
    at incrementCounter (App.jsx?t=1714542208954:31:18)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback2 (react-dom_client.js?v=38cf15c3:3672:22)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom_client.js?v=38cf15c3:3697:24)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom_client.js?v=38cf15c3:3731:39)
    at invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError (react-dom_client.js?v=38cf15c3:3734:33)
    at executeDispatch (react-dom_client.js?v=38cf15c3:7014:11)
    at processDispatchQueueItemsInOrder (react-dom_client.js?v=38cf15c3:7034:15)
    at processDispatchQueue (react-dom_client.js?v=38cf15c3:7043:13)
    at dispatchEventsForPlugins (react-dom_client.js?v=38cf15c3:7051:11)
    at react-dom_client.js?v=38cf15c3:7175:20

Note: I get the error after I click on Increase button
When I try to call the setState function( setCounter ) using counter + 1 the error disappears, I cant wrap my head around the cause.
I get that pre/post fix operators are not suitable for updating react state by I wonder why is the case.
Any insights would be greatly appreciated.

This is basic Javascript, the counter state is declared const so it can not be reassigned.
const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0); // <-- const

const incrementCounter = () => {
  setCounter(++counter); // <-- ++counter is a reassignment
};

Consider the following code:


const foo = 0;
foo++; // error, can't be reassigned!



counter++ is basically synonymous to counter = counter + 1, which fails since counter can't be reassigned. Pre/Post-incrementing adds one to the current value and assigns the value back to the variable.
If you need to increment a count state in React the idiomatic method is to use a functional state update and add one to the previous state value.
const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);

const incrementCounter = () => {
  setCounter(counter => counter + 1);
};

Using setCounter(counter + 1) works similarly in that you are not reassigning or mutating the counter state, but simply updating the counter state to the result of adding 1 to its value.

++counter is like const a = 10 ; a=11 (which throws error, I get that)
on the other hand counter = counter + 1 , how is it different ?

@JohnKiruba It's not really different, that's the point. Pre/Post-incrementing adds one to the current value and assigns the new value back to the variable.

Oh got it, ++ directly modifies the state variable (i.e, const, which is not allowed ) But +1 uses counter as a value and adds to it, then passes the new value to setState. Got it, I was confused in the starting , probably overlooked this , thanks.

Just being curious, setCounter((previousState) => ++previousState) works as intended,
Is it similar in execution of  + 1

@JohnKiruba Ah, interesting. It must be the difference between pre and post fixing. In basic terms, postfix returns the value before incrementing, prefix after incrementing. I had it a bit mixed up in the other post's comments, postfix doesn't work because it returned the current state and then mutated it, and still no rerender triggered. Although using prefix appears to work I still advise against using ++ with React state as it's mutating the state reference.

I beg to differ in this case, please correct me if I'm wrong, since (previousState) => ++previousState returns a value  (as it is an arrow func/functional statements) and that value is in-turn used by the setter. which is similar to passing an update value to the setter itself. I would assume the prefix does not mutate the state in this context, (as the value is taken as arg , processed and returned as a new val. Instead of directly mutating state reference)

@JohnKiruba previousState is a reference to the current state, so ++previousState and previousState++ are both mutations right then and there. The functional state update is only a means to access the current state in order to compute the next state value. The difference is what value is returned, and I guess React is able to see that in spite of ++prev being a mutation that the returned value is different from the previous render and it works. prev++ returns the current value then mutates, so the "next" state value is the same as the "current" state value and nothing rerenders.
